# embeddedId and session.load

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 primary keys like in the following example:

```
@Entity
class User {
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverride(name="firstName", column=@Column(name="fld_firstname")
  UserId id;

  Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String idUser;
}
```

in my application when I run session.load(persistenceClass,idClass) it should return the user that its idUser is idClass. (I know that it's not trivial but the the id of the user is unique and the first name and last name are primary key as well since there can't be more than one user with the same username and password).

How can I do it without customizing for each class an SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't actually need a composite key, perhaps it would be better to use `@UniqueContraint` to ensure uniqueness:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = 
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idUser", "fld_firstName", "lastName"}))
class User {   
    @Id
    String idUser;

    @Column(name="fld_firstname")
    String firstName;       
    String lastName;       
    Integer age; 
}
```

Comment: What if firstName refers to class APPUser and it has foreign key to it? How can I map it?

Comment: @Odelya: You can use `@JoinColumn(..., referencedColumnName = "...")`.

Comment: I mean how do I map it from columnNames in @UniqueConstraint? if AppUser object has in field @id name_id am I writing the name_id in  @UniqueConstraint or the firstName?

Comment: @Odelya: I can't understand how `APPUser` is related to unique constraint in `User`.

Comment: @axavt I mean that firstName is actually an object that has id and name and I need to add the id from the first name as unique

Answer (score 2):

You should not embed firstName and lastName in the primary key.
userId should be your primary key, and you should add a unique constraint on [firstName, lastName]. BTW, putting these additional fields in the primary key only guarantees that [idUser, firstName, lastName] is unique, but you might still have two users with different idUsers, but with the same [firstName, lastName].

Now to answer the original question, I don't see where the problem is :

```
UserId userId = new UserId("theId", "theFirstName", "theLastName");
User user = (User) session.load(User.class, userId);
```